# Allow only selected strings by regex in Python

Tags: python, regex

I would like to allow my function to pass only two exact strings. Function will enable only values: "IPv4" and "IPv6". Other strings should return error.
Note: `_set_ip_version` is my helper function

```
def _set_ip_version(self, version):

        version = str(version)
        try:
            val = re.match((IPv4|IPv6), version)
        except:
            raise ValueError(val)
        out = self._set_ip_version(
            "ip version {}".format(val)
        return out
```

I would like to allow to pass only value `IPv4` or `IPv6`. Other strings should not pass.
Currently, I got ValueError even if I send `IPv4` or `IPv6` string.

Comment: What is the question here?

Comment: do you mean `re.match("(IPv4|IPv6"), version)`? not the quotes. Also, the `protocol` variable never gets set. Should that be `val` instead?

Comment: why use regex if you only look for these two exact strings? just `if 'IPv4' or 'IPv6' in version: ...do stuff`. And by the way: try a valid input to re.match like `val = re.match(('IPv4|IPv6'), version)`

Answer (score 0):

I think you must to use enums instead of string.

```
from enum import Enum

class ip_version(Enum):
    IPv4= 1
    IPv6= 2

def func(self, version):
    if isinstance(version, ip_version):
        #Do something
```